# Truncate to the nearest thousandths and ignore the remainder of the value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Can MS Excel do rounding but only up to the nearest thousandths place and ignore the rest of the decimals in a formula? I've tried value, fixed, round and none of these do what I need.

Let's say I have 100 square feet of space and I pay $1.00566399 per sq foot, I need the formula to round only up to the 5 and ignore the rest of the numbers because when you speak on longer terms it makes a difference in rate.

So I should be multiplying 100sf by $1.01 = $101.00 and not get 100sf * 1.00566399 = $101.57

Comment: I'm actually a little confused by your terminology "rounding...up to the nearest". Do you mean you want to round to the next highest value? For example this would mean that `1.00566` becomes `1.01`, and `1.01001` would become `1.02`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

=trunc(A1,5)

If you want to round up, maybe something like
=trunc((A1*10000+1)/10000,5)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `TRUNC($cellRef or number, Decimal places)` function. It reduces the number of decimal places WITHOUT rounding, then do your math.

So for example:

```
=TRUNC(1.00566399,3)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
=A1*ROUNDUP(B1,2)
```

Where A1 contains the number of square feet and B1 contains the price per square foot in it's original long decimal form.